# Weglot get_current_language redirection WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, multilingual

I made a redirection to a custom page when the cart is empty. Website is now multilingual, using weglot.
When the language is french, it should redirect the user to the french version of the custom page, same scenario when language is italian.

The redirection per se works, but I always end up on the german (initial language) version.

**Example**: When the site language is french and you click on cart (which is empty), the browser makes the following redirections:

Start: https://example.com/fr --> Clicking on cart --> https://example.com/fr/cart --> https://example.com/fr/cart-empty (where it should stay) --> https://example.com/fr/?wg-choose-original=false --> https://example.com/cart-empty

```
// Redirect if cart is empty
add_action("template_redirect", 'redirection_function');
function redirection_function(){
    global $woocommerce;
    if(is_cart()){
        if( WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0 && weglot_get_current_language()=='fr'){
            wp_safe_redirect('https://example.com/fr/cart-empty' );
            exit;
        }

        if(WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0 && weglot_get_current_language()=='it'){
            wp_safe_redirect('https://example.com/it/cart-empty' );
            exit;
        }

        if(WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
            wp_safe_redirect('https://example.com/cart-empty' );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like `weglot_get_current_language()` did not return what you expected it to.

Comment: Btw., checking the same condition three times, is unnecessary. Put the `WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0` check into your first, "outer" `if`.

Comment: @CBroe Seems so, but I do not understand why because the Weglot developer forum says this should return the language code [link](https://developers.weglot.com/wordpress/helpers-functions#weglot_get_current_language)

Comment: Then it either returned nothing (maybe calling it at this point is too early), or it returned something other than you expected. Put a `var_dump(weglot_get_current_language()); exit;` at the beginning of your callback function, and see what result that gets you.